# mapping language variations on a graphical map

Tags: graphics, mapping, variant, human-readable, human-interface

How can I make a map similar to this one?
[langugae variation on the map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIuS6.png)

I was searching for the methods If there's an online tool. There are some but they only allow to put pins on googlemaps, I need more graphical map like the one I uploaded here.